# Coletar informações de recursos do sistema

Tags: c#, .net

Estou utilizando S.O. windows, e linguagem de programação C#.

Como coletar informações de recursos do sistema em C#? processamento, memória, disco. Estou fazendo testes de desempenho, com vários clientes e um servidor usando sockets, e quero que o servidor me mostre quanto de memória, processamento, disco ele esta utilizando com quantidades diferentes de clientes se comunicando com ele, existe alguma forma de obter essas informações via código?

Comment: da uma olhada nesse link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8241/Get-System-Info-using-C e vê se ajuda

Answer (score 2):

Existe uma classe específica para esse tipo de medição de performance: `PerformanceCounter (System.Diagnostics)` - [Msdn - PerformanceCouter Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Sou adepto do menor esforço, por isto tento usar o que já está pronto e disponível.
Biblioteca para coletas:
[Performance Counter Helper](http://perfmoncounterhelper.codeplex.com/)
Ferramentas :
[PerfView](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28567) - PerfView is a performance-analysis tool that helps isolate CPU- and memory-related performance issues. 
Informações de análise:
[Chapter 13 - Detecting Processor Bottlenecks](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc750967.aspx)
[Interpreting CPU Utilization for Performance Analysis](http://blogs.technet.com/b/winserverperformance/archive/2009/08/06/interpreting-cpu-utilization-for-performance-analysis.aspx)